# Nested UIScrollViews and scrolling in the same direction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a nested UIScrollView inside another one. Both Horizontal.
My problem is: when i scroll the inner one and its already at the end (or to the other way, at start point) my outer scroll scrolls.
I want to prevent my outer scroll from scrolling: if i'm trying to scroll the inner one, even if its not moving, prevent the outer from moving.
If the inner scroll is at the end and I try scrolling, I don't get the didScroll events. I know tracking is YES, but I don't have an event for this, so I don't know when user tracked the inner scroll.
Also, I can't use touchesBegan in my VC because the inner scroll swallows that touch.
Doe's someone have any idea how to do it?

Thanks,

Noam

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing your INNER scroll view and overriding `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. This method should return the view which should accept the event. Hence when you get the scroll for INNER scroll view - you should not pass it up the responder chain (i.e. call `[super hitTest...]`). Also - you need to set the delegate for scroll views to receive the `didScroll...` and other delegate method calls.